# Have one variable have multiple values in different methods

Tags: vb.net

Trying to create a universal placeholder for all methods in my class instead of having to declare multiple varibles per class, else declaring multiple instances of a class and using its methods can be quite costly

```
dim beginIndex, endIndex as integer

public sub GetLastFiveLetters(str as string)

    ' assume string is 10 characters long
    beginIndex = 5
    endIndex = 10 
    ResetVariable() 'I want beginIndex  and endIndex to be 5 and 10 after I call this method
    return = str.substring(5, 10)

end sub

public sub GetFirstFiveLetters(str as string)

    'assume string is 10 characters long
    beginIndex = 0
    endIndex = 5 
    ResetVariable() 'I want beginIndex  and endIndex to be 0 and 5 after I call this method

    return = str.substring(0, 5)

end sub

public sub ResetVariables()

    beginIndex = 0
    endIndex = 0

end sub
```

The reset variable method is simply there for example purposes, what i want to do is be able to use a variable with multiple values across multiple methods...
So when i call reset variable, even though im technically reseting the variable across all methods, i want to variables to retain their method specific values ... so in the first method even though i called the reset method, i want beginIndex to still be 5 and endIndex to still be 10, it is only in the resetvariable method where beginIndex will be 0 and endIndex will be 0

Comment: are you looking for global variable ?

Comment: I disagree with your prologue/premise.  This seems much more convoluted, error prone and high maintenance than local variables with limited scope

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're actually trying to accomplish here.  If you don't want the values of those variables to change, why call a method that changes them?  What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: You've shown independent methods that set class level variables, but haven't described why this doesn't work the way you want. None of your methods seem to depend on the initial value of those variables. What are you trying to do? Your comment about "declaring static methods inside methods" is also confusing.

Comment: This has got to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you find declaring and using classes "costly" (in what terms? Lines of code? MIPS? Man-Hours to type `new`?), you might want to revisit how you are using them or how they are constructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding storing variables in methods:

> ... declaring multiple instances of a class and using its methods can be quite costly

WRONG. Variables declared in methods, i.e. *local variables*, exist only while the method is being executed. On the other hand, variables declared at the class level, i.e. *fields*, exist for each class instance or object for its the whole life time.

You must make a distinction between the variable declaration and the memory that a variable uses at runtime. The variable declaration itself is not compiled into code. Only the variable accesses (i.e. setting or reading the variable) are. At runtime, local variables start to exist when a method is called and cease to exist after the method returns.

Class fields, however, exist as long as the objects exist, whether a method is being called or not.